# Calculating range for all variables

Tags: r, range

For someone new to R, what is the best way to view the range for a number of variables? I've run the summary command on the entire dataset, can I do range () on the entire dataset as well or do i need to create variables for each variable in the dataset?

Answer (score 1):

For individual variable, you can use `range`. To see the range of multiple variables, you can combine `range` with one of the apply functions. See below for an example.

```
range(iris$Sepal.Length)
# [1] 4.3 7.9

sapply(iris[, 1:4], range)

#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#[1,]          4.3         2.0          1.0         0.1
#[2,]          7.9         4.4          6.9         2.5
```

(only the first four columns were selected from `iris` since the 5th is a factor, and range doesn't apply for factors)